# php xamarin not returning echo

Tags: php, android, xamarin

i am building an android app that connects to my mysql server, inserts a new user and returns an id or a error string. my problem is i do the upload from c# it proforms the php as i can see the user in the db, but it does get to the Client_UploadDataComplete.

i see the first 2 toast elements but not the 3rd. my php works from a web browser. also this is all on a dialog fragment.

php is:

```
<?php
    function create_password_hash($strPassword, $numAlgo = 1, $arrOptions = array())
    {
        if (function_exists('password_hash')) {
            // php >= 5.5
            $hash = password_hash($strPassword, $numAlgo, $arrOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
            $salt = base64_encode($salt);
            $salt = str_replace('+', '.', $salt);
            $hash = crypt($strPassword, '$2y$10$' . $salt . '$');
        }
        return $hash;
    }

    function verify_password_hash($strPassword, $strHash)
    {
        if (function_exists('password_verify')) {
            // php >= 5.5
            $boolReturn = password_verify($strPassword, $strHash);
        } else {
            $strHash2 = crypt($strPassword, $strHash);
            echo $strHash2."<BR>";
            $boolReturn = $strHash == $strHash2;
        }
        return $boolReturn;
    }

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
    // check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
      echo ('Database connection failed: '  .mysqli_connect_error);
    }
    else
    {
        $id="";
        $firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $encryptedPassword = create_password_hash($password);
        $code = $_REQUEST['code'];
        $diabetes = $_REQUEST['diabetes'];
        $bloodpressure = $_REQUEST['bloodpressure'];
        $fitness = $_REQUEST['fitness'];
        $cholesteral = $_REQUEST['cholesterol'];
        $codeId = "";
        $result = "";

        $strHash2 = crypt($password, $encryptedPassword);
        $boolReturn = ($encryptedPassword == $strHash2); 

        $stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM mentor where mcode = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $code);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($codeId);

        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();

        if(($stmt->num_rows)===1)
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email,encrypted_password,diabetes,cholesterol,bloodPressure,fitnessTraining,mentor_id) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssiiiii',$firstName,$lastName,$email,$encryptedPassword,$diabetes,$cholesteral,$bloodpressure,$fitness,$codeId);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->fetch();

            $id = $conn->insert_id;
            echo $id;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "mentor id is invalid";
        }

        /*
        //check hash vs password
        if (verify_password_hash($password, $encryptedPassword)) 
        {
            echo 'Password is valid!';
        } else 
        {
            echo 'Invalid password.';
        }
        */
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();

    }   

?>
```

my c# is:

```
private void _btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (CheckFields())
        {
            //save to db
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.sbmgroup.ca/test/biteboard/CreateContact.php");

            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

            string diabetesValue = itemChecked(_diabetes.Checked);
            string cholesterolValue = itemChecked(_cholesertal.Checked);
            string fitnessValue = itemChecked(_fitness.Checked);
            string bloodValue = itemChecked(_bloodPressure.Checked);

            parameters.Add("firstName", _firstName.Text);
            parameters.Add("lastName", _lastName.Text);
            parameters.Add("email", _email.Text);
            parameters.Add("password", _password.Text);
            parameters.Add("code", _mentorCode.Text);
            parameters.Add("diabetes", diabetesValue);
            parameters.Add("bloodpressure", bloodValue);
            parameters.Add("fitness", fitnessValue);
            parameters.Add("cholesterol", cholesterolValue);

            Toast.MakeText(Activity.ApplicationContext, "before upload", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            client.UploadDataCompleted += Client_UploadDataCompleted;
            client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
            Toast.MakeText(Activity.ApplicationContext, "after upload", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
}


private void Client_UploadDataCompleted(object sender, UploadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Toast.MakeText(Activity.ApplicationContext, "upload complete", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        string id = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
        int newId = 0;

        if (OnSignupComplete != null)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(id, out newId))
            {
                OnSignupComplete.Invoke(this, new OnSignupEventArgs(newId, _firstName.Text, _lastName.Text, _email.Text, _password.Text, _retypePassword.Text, _mentorCode.Text, _bloodPressure.Checked, _cholesertal.Checked, _fitness.Checked, _diabetes.Checked));
                this.Dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UploadValuesAsync` fires the `UploadValuesCompleted` event.  You are using `UploadDataCompleted`, which is fired by the `UploadDataAsync` method.